# Getting specific key from factor object using doc value in Elasticsearch

Tags: sorting, groovy, scripting, elasticsearch

I'm using a basic Elasticsearch sorting script to sort documents by quality. Since we are storing quality as "low", "med" and "high" it doesn't work to do a basic sort, since their alphabetical order is not the same as their perceived enumerated order.

Here's the script I'm using:

```
"sort":{
      "_script":{
      "script":"factor[doc['quality'].value]",
      "type":"number",
      "params":{
            "factor": {
                  "high": 2,
                  "med": 1,
                  "low": 0
            }
      },
      "order":"asc"

}
```

If I replace `doc['quality'].value` with `'high'` it works just fine, so it seems there's an issue accepting the doc value as the key for the object.

Any insight on why this is would be greatly appreciated.

*The error I get is as follows:*

```
ScriptSortParser$2@1135e7f9>]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: NullPointerException; }]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default language of Elasticsearch is groovy and this is not the format to access a map.
The following should work for you

```
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "script": "factor.get(doc['quality'].value)",
      "type": "number",
      "params": {
        "factor": {
          "high": 2,
          "med": 1,
          "low": 0
        }
      },
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

For more reference on the topic and how to use groovy(1) in elasticsearch scripting(2) you can refer these references [1](http://blog.qbox.io/introduction-to-elasticsearch-scripting),[2](http://blog.qbox.io/elasticsearch-scripting-sorting)

Comment: Thank you! I figured my syntax was not correct. I'm still a groovy newbie.